# How to interact with MongoDB from Python-Quart?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask-sqlalchemy, quart

I'm building a small web service and I'm using Python Quart, the async version of Flask.

The web services will get data from a MongoDB, run some operations on it and return a JSON. On Flask I would use something like Flask-mongoalchemy.

Is there any similar library to be used with Quart? What would be the best way to integrate MongoDB with Python Quart?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use straight up `pymongo`?

Comment: Or for async use the async PyMongo package Motor.